# Incorrect syntax in query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Hello i have this query :

```
strSQL =    "SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,ArriveDate) AS God," & _

"COUNT (CASE  DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) WHEN 1 THEN DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) END)As m1 ," & _
"COUNT (CASE  DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) WHEN 2 THEN DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) END)As m2 ," & _
"COUNT (CASE  DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) WHEN 3 THEN DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) END)As m3 ," & _
"COUNT (CASE  DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) WHEN 4 THEN DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) END)As m4 " & _

 " FROM Company " & _

  " WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,ArriveDate) =" & [Forms]![Raport_lunar_anual_carnete]![ANUL] & _

  " AND DATEPART(mm,ArriveDate)= " & [Forms]![Raport_lunar_anual_carnete]![LUNA] & _

  " GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy,ArriveDate)"
```

It says me that : **Incorrect syntax near the keyword "AND"**

Comment: maybe try to remove comma (`,`) in this part `As m4 ,` to become `As m4`. That will trigger error in SQL server, not sure about ms access

Comment: i removed it , also this eror

Comment: try to debug, put break point after the code above and see `strSQL` string outputted. Post the string if you don't have idea after looking at it.

Comment: Access SQL does not recognize `CASE WHEN`.  If your query is being run by Access' database engine, investigate `IIf()` or `Switch()` as Access-compatible alternatives to `CASE WHEN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
strSQL =          " SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,ArriveDate) AS God,"    
strSQL = strSQL & "   COUNT (CASE  DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) WHEN 1 THEN DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) END)As m1 ,"
strSQL = strSQL & "   COUNT (CASE  DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) WHEN 2 THEN DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) END)As m2 ," 
strSQL = strSQL & "   COUNT (CASE  DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) WHEN 3 THEN DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) END)As m3 ," 
strSQL = strSQL & "   COUNT (CASE  DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) WHEN 4 THEN DATEPART(d,ArriveDate) END)As m4 ,"    
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM Company "     
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,ArriveDate) =" & [Forms]![Raport_lunar_anual_carnete]![ANUL] &     
strSQL = strSQL & " AND DATEPART(mm,ArriveDate)= " & [Forms]![Raport_lunar_anual_carnete]![LUNA] &     
strSQL = strSQL & " GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy,ArriveDate)"
```

Comment: it tells me that he coundn't find procedure false on this modified query